# creating list of tables created by functions

Tags: r

I am trying to create a list of tables created by output of function. i have tried many ways but not working.

```
    df <- 
      mtcars[1:8,4:ncol(mtcars)] %>% 
      rownames_to_column(var = "model")
    
    
    df1 <- subset(df, vs==1)
    df2 <- subset(df, am==1)
    df3 <- subset(df, gear==3)
    
    df_list <- list(df1,df2,df3)
    banner <- c("T1","T2","T3")
    
    
    func1<-function(df,list_var,....){
      
        table_list<-list()
        for (i in 1:length(df_list)) {
          
          table_list[[i]]<-sub_fun(df, list_var[i])
          
          t1 <- do.call(rbind,table_list)
# this sub function is creating a frequency table for multiple columns 
# t1 is a table here and this loop create table like t1, t2 , t3          
        }
        
        colnames(t1)[1] <- banner[[d]]
# here i am changing the name of first row of table like "T1"
        
# my question is here i want to create a list of tables and convert them #into a single data frame of list of dataframes above
        table_list1[i] <- t1
        t2 <- t2 <- Reduce(bind_rows, table_list1)
      t2
    }
```

the output should be like a single data frame with one blank row between them. so for example if function produces three tables then output should be like three dataframes, one below another and that will become single dataframe final.

#Desired output enter image description here
[image]

Reproducible example

```
df <- mtcars

df1 <- subset(df, vs==1)
df2 <- subset(df, am==1)
df3 <- subset(df, gear==3)

df_list <- list(df1,df2,df3)
banner <- c("T1","T2","T3")


sub_fun<-function(db,var){
  var = rlang::parse_expr(var)
  
  df1<- db %>% filter(!is.na(!!var)) %>%   summarise(
    Median =quantile(!!var, type=6, probs = seq(0, 1, 0.25), na.rm=TRUE)[3],
    Mean =  mean(!! var, na.rm=TRUE),
    N = sum(!is.na(!!var)))
  df1
  
  }
  
func1<-function(db,list_var,....){
  
  for (d in 1:length(df_list)) {
    table_list1<-list()
    table_list<-list()
    for (i in 1:length(list_var)) {
      
      
      table_list[[i]]<-sub_fun(db, list_var[i])
      
      t1 <- do.call(rbind,table_list)
      
    }
 #after this i want to create a list of table produced by t1, and then #create single in final table "t_final" as list of tables    
    # #colnames(t1)[1] <- banner[[d]]
    # table_list1[[i]] <- t1
    # sep_line <- rep("", ncol(table_list1[[i]]))
    # table_list1 <- lapply(table_list1[[i]], function(x)x %>%
    #                         mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~round(.x, 2)),
    #                                across(everything(), ~as.character(.x))) %>%
    #                         rbind(., sep_line))
    # 
    # t2 <- bind_rows(table_list1)
    # rownames(t2) <- NULL
    # t2 <- t2[-nrow(t2), ]
  t1 <- t_final  
  t_final
  
  }
}

debug(func1)
func1(db=df,list_var=c("cyl","disp","hp"))
```

output is like
[image]

Comment: Pasting three datasets together like that is reasonably straightforward, but all values must be converted to character strings to make it work.  I'm not exactly sure what the function is supposed to be doing, though.  I'll submit an answer to the pasting three datasets together below and we can go from there.

Comment: I just updated the question where i am getting stuck , at line table_list1[i] <- t1.
now you will have understanding of i am trying to do

Comment: I updated the answer to include what I think the function would look like. Without a reproducible example, I can't be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- 
  mtcars[1:8,4:ncol(mtcars)] %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var = "model")
  df1 <- subset(df, vs==1)
df2 <- subset(df, am==1)
df3 <- subset(df, gear==3)
sep_line <- rep("", ncol(df1))
df_list <- list(df1, df1, df1)
df_list <- lapply(df_list, function(x)x %>% mutate(across(everything(), as.character)) %>% rbind(., sep_line))
res <- bind_rows(df_list)
rownames(res) <- NULL
res <- res[-nrow(res), ]
res
#>             model  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1      Datsun 710  93 3.85  2.32 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> 2  Hornet 4 Drive 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> 3         Valiant 105 2.76  3.46 20.22  1  0    3    1
#> 4       Merc 240D  62 3.69  3.19    20  1  0    4    2
#> 5                                                     
#> 6      Datsun 710  93 3.85  2.32 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> 7  Hornet 4 Drive 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> 8         Valiant 105 2.76  3.46 20.22  1  0    3    1
#> 9       Merc 240D  62 3.69  3.19    20  1  0    4    2
#> 10                                                    
#> 11     Datsun 710  93 3.85  2.32 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> 12 Hornet 4 Drive 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> 13        Valiant 105 2.76  3.46 20.22  1  0    3    1
#> 14      Merc 240D  62 3.69  3.19    20  1  0    4    2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Without a reproducible example, I can't be sure, but implementing this in your function should look something like this:

```r
func1<-function(df,list_var,....){
  
  table_list<-list()
  for (i in 1:length(df_list)) {
    
    table_list[[i]]<-sub_fun(df, list_var[i])
    
    t1 <- do.call(rbind,table_list)
    # this sub function is creating a frequency table for multiple columns 
    # t1 is a table here and this loop create table like t1, t2 , t3          

    # here i am changing the name of first row of table like "T1"
    colnames(t1)[1] <- banner[[d]]
    
    # my question is here i want to create a list of tables and convert them #into a single data frame of list of dataframes above
    table_list1[i] <- t1
    
  }
  
  
  sep_line <- rep("", ncol(table_list[[1]]))
  table_list <- lapply(table_list, function(x)x %>% 
                         mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~round(.x, 2)), 
                                across(everything(), ~as.character(.x))) %>% 
                         rbind(., sep_line))
  res <- bind_rows(table_list)
  rownames(res) <- NULL
  res <- res[-nrow(res), ]
  res
}
```

Comment: t1 <- do.call(rbind,table_list)
    
    }
    table_list1[[i]] <- t1
    sep_line <- rep("", ncol(table_list1[[i]]))
    table_list1 <- lapply(table_list1[[i]], function(x)x %>%
                           mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~round(.x, 2)),
                                  across(everything(), ~as.character(.x))) %>%
                           rbind(., sep_line))
    }
  
  t2 <- bind_rows(table_list1)
  rownames(t2) <- NULL
  t2 <- t2[-nrow(t2), ]
  t2

Comment: I am trying this way but getting error  no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "character"
 table_list1[[i]] <- t1 , so here table_list1 is list creating  for tables

Comment: any idea what i am doing here ...??

Comment: If you could post a reproducible example of what you're doing and what error it produces, I can probably figure it out.

Comment: I have created a reproducible example , now you can test on your side. let me know in case any more questions.